# S3 cli includes not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Alright I'm very confused by aws cli

I have an S3 bucket:

```
s3://my-bucket
  directory/
    file1
    file2
  backup-logs-1234
  backup-logs-5678
```

I've verified that the files are in the s3 bucket, and I can see them with `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`

I'm trying to delete all the backup logs in the folder (8000 of them).  I've tried every combination of includes/excludes I can think of

1) For some reason `aws s3 rm "s3://my-bucket/" --include "*backup-logs*" --dryrun` tries to delete `s3://my-bucket/directory/`

2) `aws s3 rm "s3://my-bucket/" --exclude "*" --include "*backup-logs*" --dryrun` doesn't see any files to delete

3) I've also tried different substrings of "backup" (eg. b, ba, back)

4) I've also tried adding recursive (even though I don't want it to be) and it finds all the files in `directory/` that match the pattern, but none of the top level ones

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.  Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*backup-logs*"` should work.

When you want to delete multiple objects within your bucket

> --recursive  (boolean)  Command  is  performed  on all files or objects
>          under the specified directory or prefix.

You can read on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters about include/exclude use

Comment: Ah, so you have to use recursive even if you only care about one level?  That's nonintuitive.  Got it to work, your answer is close but I also have to add exclude or else it includes everything: `aws s3 rm "s3://my-bucket" --exclude "*" --include "*backup-logs*" --recursive`.  Thanks!

Comment: this doesnt work if you have *backup-logs* in *directory*

Comment: I was doing a --exclude "*" --include "index.html" to set a no cache on only that file since it changes and it wasn't updating.  I had to add --recursive then it did.  Not sure if it is some relative or root pathing issue but the files directly in the root of the bucket.